# Update parent state when Vuetify snackbar timeouts

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Currently I have a `Parent` and a `Child` component. In the `Parent` component I set the `snackbar` state to `true` after a successful API call so it shows the snackbar. When I click on the `close button` in the snackbar the state of the Parent gets updated and the snackbar disappears. However, when the snackbar timeouts I get the following error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "snackbar"

How can I update the Parent state when the snackbar timeouts? Is there a clean way to do this?

This is my Parent component:

```
<Snackbar :snackbar="snackbar" :y="bottom" :text="text" @update-snackbar="updateSnackbar"></Snackbar>

<script>
    import Snackbar from "../components/Snackbar";

    export default {
        name: "AddFriend",
        components: {Snackbar},
        methods: {
            updateSnackbar(e) {
                this.snackbar = e;
            },
            add() {
                const username = "test";
                axios
                    .post('/api/friend/add',
                        {
                            username: username
                        })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.success) {
                            this.snackbar = true;
                            this.text = 'Request successfully send!';
                        } else {
                            this.snackbar = true;
                            this.text = response.data.error;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
                        this.snackbar = true;
                        this.text = 'test';
                    })
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                error: null,
                valid: false,
                text: null,
                snackbar: false,
                bottom: 'bottom',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my Child (snackbar) component:

```
<template>
    <v-snackbar
            v-model="snackbar"
            :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
            :timeout="1500"
            :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
    >
        {{ text }}
        <v-btn
                color="red"
                flat
                @click="closeSnackbar(false)"
        >
            Close
        </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Snackbar",
        props: {
            snackbar: Boolean,
            y: String,
            x: null,
            mode: String,
            text: String
        },
        methods: {
            closeSnackbar(snackbar) {
                this.$emit('update-snackbar', snackbar);
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

If someone knows how to do this please let me know. Also if a CodeSandBox is needed I will create one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to update the parent state on timeout. I did this by adding:

```
@input="closeSnackbar"
```

to my v-snackbar. When the timeout occurs it now triggers the closeSnackbar function which updates my parent component. For everyone with the same problems here is my full snackbar component:

```
<template>
    <v-snackbar
            :value="snackbar"
            @input="closeSnackbar"
            bottom
            :timeout="1500"
    >
        {{ text }}
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Snackbar",
        props: {
            snackbar: Boolean,
            text: String
        },
        methods: {
            closeSnackbar(snackbar) {
                this.$emit('update-snackbar', snackbar);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```